# Inconsistency detected error while launching UnityHub.AppImage on Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kali-linux, ubuntu-unity, unity3d

I am using kali Linux and I want to install unityHUb.AppImage. First I Did is

chmod +x UnityHub.AppImage

but when I tried to launch the image by command

./UnityHub.AppImage

It gives the following error

" Inconsistency detected by ld.so: ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h: 540: elf_machine_rela_relative: Assertion `ELFW(R_TYPE) (reloc->r_info) == R_X86_64_RELATIVE' failed!"

I am using kali Linux in dual-boot with mate desktop environment

Comment: Kali Linux is not intended to be installed or used as a general-purpose OS. Please read [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me).

Comment: Still I want to set it up?

Comment: Please click the link I've posted and read the top answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out

Comment: Sorry, but sometimes the most helpful thing you can do is tell someone that they're wasting their time doing things that don't make sense. If you want a general-purpose Kali, just use Debian. It's what Kali is using as its base and it's actually an all-round OS, not a specialized suite of tools you shouldn't try to modify.

Comment: Yes that's why I am Installing Ubuntu. But now I am stuck at grub2